# Principle and Practice or Principles and Practices? A Grammatical Question

Tags: nouns, titles, grammaticality

A very simple question: I have come up with a title for a project and don't know whether to use the singular or plural: 'Principle and practice for betterment' or 'Principles and practices for betterment'.

Which one is correct or are they both grammatically sound in the context of being a project title?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is that the whole of your project title because 'betterment' is a word usually used in a specific context rather than in the abstract like that.

Comment: Thanks for the tip!